# Where to run long automated scans?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners, scan, web-scanners

I'm trying to run some automated scans without stopping for long periods of time (each scan can take anywhere from 8 hours to 3 days). I currently don't have a PC I can leave running for many days without shutting down, nor can I afford to rent some machines to run it for me.

I've tried running my scans on a VirtualBox VM, saving the machine state and continuing when I can. However, due to some unclear problems, the machine just freezes after some hours and I lose my process.

I know Google Collab allows people to run AI training on it for free but I'm running scans like skipfish, Nessus, Nexpose, etc. so I'm not sure if I can use that for my scans.

Is there a service where I can run my long scans for free?

Comment: This is not really a security question. It is a request for free services which run your scans instead.  Such questions are off-topic.

Comment: Lots of scanners save their state when you stop them so they can pick up where they left off ...

Comment: The ones I'm using don't save so I have to keep it running without pausing. Also, I'd hoped this wouldn't be too off-topic since I thought many security people (mainly PenTesters) would have faced something like this.

Comment: You've asked for a service, which makes this off-topic. If you focused on the *problem* instead of what you want as a preferred *solution*, we can answer that.

Comment: @JohnZhau -- Vulnerability scans take time--there's no way around that.  If you have limited time on target for some reason, break the scan up.  Most of the scanners you mentioned allow you to control what and how much get scanned.  For example, Nessus:  if you're using one of the built-in scans, that checks for everything + the kitchen sink, create X number of scans from the built-in (e.g. Phase 1-X).  That way, you can compartmentalize the scan to run in more discrete fragments thereby knowing where you left off and can continue from that point on the next run.

Comment: Not sure why you cannot afford an always-on machine. If you do professional pentesting, you do have a budget. If you do it personally, the number of targets would be low enough that the test suite finishes in reasonable time. Unless you're doing illegal stuff, personally trying to break into systems that you are not authorized to.